# LinqToXML Optimisation Query

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-xml

How can I simplify this?

I have an XML file like:

```
<Root>
    <Header />
    <Content />
    <Content />
    <Content />
    <!-- …. Lots of Contents -->
    <Footer />
</Root>
```

I need to split into smaller files so that each file has a 'Header' and a 'Footer' and then X many 'Content's.
My current method takes a copy of the main file, removes all Content’s and then adds the required based on skip & take.

I don’t like it because I am copying the original into memory each time, removing stuff and then adding some of the stuff I've just removed:

```
while (index < totalContents) {
    var newXDoc = new XDocument(xDoc);
    newXDoc.Descendants("Content").Remove();
    newXDoc.Root.Element("Header").AddAfterSelf(
        xDoc
            .Descendants("Content")
            .Skip(index)
            .Take(ordersPerFile)
    );

    xmlDocs.Add(XmlConverter.ToXmlDocument(newXDoc));

    index += ordersPerFile;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to perform this task?

I'm looking for something like:

```
while (index < totalContents) {
    var newXDoc = new XDocument(
        xDoc.Where(x => x.ContentElementsThatIWantForThisIteration...)
    );

    xmlDocs.Add(XmlConverter.ToXmlDocument(newXDoc));

    index += ordersPerFile;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to simulate *paging*, so it all could be placed within one query.

```
var header = xDoc.Root.Element("Header");
var footer = xDoc.Root.Element("Footer");
var contents = xDoc.Root.Elements("Content")

var newXDocs = contents.Select((c, i) => new { c, i })
                       .GroupBy(x => x.i / ordersPerFile)
                       .Select(x => new XDocument(
                                       new XElement("Root",
                                           header,
                                           x.Select(y => y.c),
                                           footer)))
                       .ToList();
```

btw. using `Descendants` makes the query traverse whole XML tree, so it's better to use `Elements`

Comment: Have tried both of these solutions and they both work perfectly, it's a shame I can't mark both as answer! Thanks for the tip re. Elements vs Descendants :)

Comment: Create the `XNamespace` instance and change `new XElement("Root"` into `new XElement(ns +"Root",`.

Comment: Yea I figured it out soon after I asked you the question. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 4):

Well I would fetch the header and the footer *once* - and then personally use the `Batch` method from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var header = doc.Root.Element("Header");
var footer = doc.Root.Element("Footer");
var contents = doc.Root.Elements("Contents");

var newDocs = contents.Batch(ordersPerFile)
                      .Select(middle => new XDocument(
                                 new XElement("Root", header, middle, footer)))
                      .ToList();
```

If you don't want to use MoreLINQ, you could create a `List<XElement>` for all the contents, then either use `Skip`/`Take` to create the batches, or explicitly fetch them by index. (Marcin's approach of grouping by division is a good one.) I'd suggest using MoreLINQ though - you may well find it's useful for you in other ways.

(Disclaimer: I started the MoreLINQ project, but it's grown since then. It's easily installable via its [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/morelinq) though.)

Comment: Have tried both of these solutions and they both work perfectly, it's a shame I can't mark both as answer. Thanks and gratz with MoreLinq. I haven't yet, but I will check that out.

Comment: Didn't know that you started MoreLINQ :)